# VueJS - Property or method "currentUser" is not defined on the instance

Tags: vue.js

I have a component where I initialize an empty object `currentUser` in `data()` property and an HTML template that references `currentUser` defined in the component but I get an error:

```
Property or method "currentUser" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property
```

This is my code.

#### userProfile.vue

```
<template src='./userProfile.html'><template>
<script>
  export default {
    data(){
      return {
        currentUser: {
          username: '',
          email: '',
          phoneNumber: '',
          firstName: '',
          lastName: '',
          hourlyRate: '',
          joined: '',
          twitterUrl: '',
          facebookUrl: '',
          linkedInUrl: '',
          avatar: {}
        }
      }
    },
    created(){      

    }
  }
</script>
```

#### userProfile.html

```
<div class="profile-img">
    <img :src="currentUser.avatar.url" alt=""/>
    <h5>{{currentUser.first_name + ' ' + currentUser.last_name}}</h5>
</div>
```

I don't understand why I am getting this error. `currentUser` is defined in the component.

Comment: Have you tried testing the template inline instead of including it as a separate file?

Comment: maybe because your template is not properly closed :  I see <template> instead of </template>

Comment: Oh my God! Yes, this was the problem @Istopopoki I can't believe I made such a typoo :) Sorry and thank you for the help:)

Comment: I copy pasted your code in VS Code and the text colors were showing something was wrong immediately...very useful, especially with the Vetur plugin. I recommend it !

Comment: It's weird that SublimeText 3 did not show me that. I need to improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your template is not properly closed : I see < template > instead of < /template >.